# Datatables: Change cell color based on values

Tags: datatables

I am using DataTable to create an interactive table. I have 9 columns, 5 of which are values. I want to change the background color of each cell based on their specific.

I have started off trying to change the entire row color first as this seemed like an easier task. However I can't get anything to change.

My code is below:

```html
<head>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>      
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#countryTable').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#countryTable ').DataTable({
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                if ( aData[3] > 11.7 )
                {
                    $(nRow).css('color', 'red')
                }
                else if ( aData[2] == "4" )
                {
                    $(nRow).css('color', 'green')
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
    
</head>

<body>      

    <table id ="countryTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" data-page-length='193'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Beer</th>
        <th>Wine</th>
        <th>Spirits</th>
        <th>Other</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Estonia</td>
        <td>EE</td>
        <td>14.97</td>
        <td>5.87</td>
        <td>1.65</td>
        <td>5.64</td>
        <td>1.81</td>
        <td>3 - Medium Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Belarus</td>
        <td>BY</td>
        <td>14.44</td>
        <td>2.5</td>
        <td>0.75</td>
        <td>6.73</td>
        <td>4.46</td>
        <td>4 - Very Risky</td>
    </tr>
  
</tbody>
```

I have also tried using the following function but to no luck.
If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated as I am very new to JavaScript.

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
        $('#countryTable').DataTable({
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                if ( aData[3] == "5" )
                {
                    $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Red');
                }
                else if ( aData[3] == "4" )
                {
                    $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Orange');
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try seeing this http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html

Comment: Use 1.10 specific function when you're using `DataTable` initialization

Answer (score 68, accepted):

First of all, initialize `DataTable` only once. Then as per your question, use `rowCallback` and not `fnRowCallBack` as shown below:

```
var oTable = $('#countryTable').DataTable({ 
    'rowCallback': function(row, data, index){
    if(data[3]> 11.7){
        $(row).find('td:eq(3)').css('color', 'red');
    }
    if(data[2].toUpperCase() == 'EE'){
        $(row).find('td:eq(2)').css('color', 'blue');
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr77dgmt/76/)

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I have tried using the above code but it is still not working for me. Where do I insert it? Do I add it in with the following?      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#countryTable').DataTable();
        });
    </script> Sorry If it seems basic I am very new to this.

Comment: @Amy I suggest you read the examples and the documentation from [here](https://www.datatables.net/examples/index). This will allow you to get a hold of the syntax and the basic operation. One step at a time. Check the fiddle and relate it to other examples.

Comment: Thank you that link really helped. I was putting the code in the wrong place. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @philantrovert Bravo! I implemented it and just put minimum amount for stores income. Data is changing and I would like to change color for top ten numbers, possible? How can I select only 10 top(highest) numbers in a table?

Comment: @HerculesS. I'm sorry I haven't worked enough with DataTables to answer that. I believe you should ask that as a new question.

Comment: @philantrovert Hey, i found a way: 
rowCallback: function(row, data, index){
if(data[5]> 4900){
$(row).find('td:eq(5)').addClass('greencolor');} It finds 5th td and checks if number is larger 4900 :) and adds class to it.