# How to find a value in a jQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am trying to find a value in the first column on a datatable, and colored the row when this value is found.

I tried this :

```
$.each(table.column(0), function(key, value){
  if(value==="value"){
    table.row(0).css('background-color', 'red');
  }
})
```

then this:

```
for(var i =0; i<table.row(0).length; i++){
  if(table.column(0).item(i).data() === "value"){
    table.row(i).css('background-color', 'red');   
  }
}
```

But nothing worked.

Comment: You can show us a [mre] - ideally as a runnable, self-contained [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365).  First of all, can you show us your research? For example, there is [Datatables: Change cell color based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41053046/12567365), and also many [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatable+highlight+cells+site:stackoverflow.com). If none of those help, you can clarify by showing your MRE and telling us where you are specifically getting stuck.

Comment: Could you share with us what you have tried so far so that people will well understand your need and could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop inside your datatable after bind using `YourTable.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop){` and add desire class whatever needed.

Example:

```
var YourTable = $('#table').DataTable({}); // Bind your table first.

YourTable .rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop){
         var rowData = this.data();
         if(rowData.value  == "value"){
            $(this.node()).addClass('YourClass');
        }
});
```

On CSS:

```
.YourClass{
  background-color: red
}
```

Note: Dont confuse with `rowData.value`, its field name just like `first name`, `Email` .........